# VisualStateManager.SetVisualStateGroups UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I am using Xamarin to develop an App in Android, iOS and UWP.

Can someone please explain me why the following works fine on Android and iOS, but not on UWP?

I have a custom control that inherits from Xamarin.Forms.Button:

```cs
public class CustomButton : Xamarin.Forms.Button
    {
        public CustomButton()
        {
            BorderWidth = ButtonStyle.BorderWidth;

            VisualStateManager.SetVisualStateGroups(
                this,
                new VisualStateGroupList()
                {
                    new VisualStateGroup()
                    {
                        States =
                        {
                            ButtonStyle.NormalState,
                            ButtonStyle.PressedState,
                            ButtonStyle.MouseOverState,
                            ButtonStyle.DisabledState
                        }
                    }
                });

        }
    }


public static class ButtonStyle
    {
        public static Color TextColor { get; } = Colors.ButtonText;
        public static Color BackgroundColor { get; } = Colors.SubtleAccent;
        public static double BorderWidth { get; } = Parameters.ButtonBorderWidth;
        public static double CornerRadius(double FontSize) => 0.5 * FontSize;

        public static VisualState NormalState { get; } =
            new VisualState
            {
                Name = "Normal",
                Setters =
                {
                    new Setter { Property = Button.TextColorProperty, Value = Colors.ButtonText },
                    new Setter { Property = Button.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Colors.SubtleAccent },
                    new Setter { Property = Button.BorderColorProperty, Value = Colors.ButtonText },
                    new Setter { Property = Button.PaddingProperty, Value = new Thickness(5,0) },
                    new Setter { Property = Button.MarginProperty, Value = new Thickness(0, 0) }
                }
            };

        public static VisualState PressedState { get; } =
            new VisualState
            {
                Name = "Pressed",
                Setters =
                {
                    new Setter { Property = Button.TextColorProperty, Value = Colors.ButtonText },
                    new Setter { Property = Button.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Colors.SubtleAccent },
                    new Setter { Property = Button.BorderColorProperty, Value = Colors.Accent },
                    new Setter { Property = Button.PaddingProperty, Value = new Thickness(0,0) },
                    new Setter { Property = Button.MarginProperty, Value = new Thickness(5, 0) }
                }
            };

        public static VisualState MouseOverState { get; } =
            new VisualState
            {
                Name = "PointerOver",
                Setters =
                {
                    new Setter { Property = Button.TextColorProperty, Value = Colors.ButtonText },
                    new Setter { Property = Button.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Colors.SubtleAccent },
                    new Setter { Property = Button.BorderColorProperty, Value = Colors.Accent },
                    new Setter { Property = Button.PaddingProperty, Value = new Thickness(5,0) },
                    new Setter { Property = Button.MarginProperty, Value = new Thickness(0, 0) }
                }
            };

        public static VisualState DisabledState { get; } =
            new VisualState
            {
                Name = "Disabled",
                Setters =
                {
                    new Setter { Property = Button.BorderColorProperty, Value = Colors.Disabled },
                    new Setter { Property = Button.TextColorProperty, Value = Colors.Disabled },
                    new Setter { Property = Button.BackgroundColorProperty, Value = Colors.GrayVeryLight },
                    new Setter { Property = Button.PaddingProperty, Value = new Thickness(5,0) },
                    new Setter { Property = Button.MarginProperty, Value = new Thickness(0, 0) }
                }
            };
    }
```

On UWP the VisualState "Normal" and "Pressed" work fine, but the other ones don't, I just get the default style for the Xamarin.Forms.Button "PointerOver" or "Disabled"

As I said before, on Android and iOS works as expected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On UWP the VisualState "Normal" and "Pressed" work fine, but the other ones don't, I just get the default style for the Xamarin.Forms.Button "PointerOver" or "Disabled"

Derive from official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual-state-manager), the default `VisualStateManager` visual state group named "CommonStates" with the following visual states: `"Normal" "Disabled" "Focused" "Selected"`, it does not contains `PointerOver` state, so `PointerOver` will not work. for android and ios, they don't have `PointerOver` state. If you do want this feature, We suggest you use custom button render and set `PointerOver` on the native button control.

Comment: Okey, I understand that PointerOver doesn't work. But what about Disabled? Disabled state isn't working

Comment: Yep, I found that, it looks `Disabled` does not work for button, I have tested Disabled within Entry, it work correct. Please report this behavior in xamarin github issue box.

Comment: Here's the report link: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12984